# Upload file to directory specified by $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, upload

I know how to upload to php but not using a $_SESSION['user_folder'] to define the directory

As it stands each users folder is created via md5 encryption and when they log in the $_SESSION[user_folder] is carried through

As it stands I have tried a couple of different upload ways but to no avail the code currently looks like this but when it is run i recieve two errors:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\Upload.php on line 54

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php27B4.tmp' to '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6\' in C:\wamp\www\Upload.php on line 54

http://pastebin.com/GGBrRtDu

Comment: What kind of path is `$_SESSION['UserFolder'] . '\\'`? That doesn't look right. Keep in mind that the 2nd argument to `move_uploaded_file` should a be _file_ not a folder.

Comment: it outputs as "userfolder\" in theory

Answer (score 0):

The error message for `move_uploaded_file()` is telling you what you're doing wrong: you're specifying a directory for the second parameter. The function doesn't work that way. The second parameter needs to be a full path to the *filename* you want the file to now be. One answer is to append the path-less filename to your target path.

(The functionality is modeled on the Unix `mv` command which is used for both renaming files as well as moving them. Combining them means you can do both in one step, if needed. As it happens, `move_uploaded_file()` wants you to both move and rename the file.)